# Killing tensor of Friedman-Robertson-Walker metric (not assuming flatness)

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields

There exists [an earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484217/killing-tensor-of-friedman-robertson-walker-metric) about how to verify that, if $U^\mu = (1,0,0,0)^\mu$ is the four-velocity of comoving observers, then

$$K_{\mu\nu} = a^2(g_{\mu\nu} + U_\mu U_\nu)\tag{1}$$

is a Killing tensor, $\nabla_{(\sigma} K_{\mu\nu)} = 0$, for the FRW metric

$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + a(t)^2 \left[\frac{dr^2}{1 - \kappa r^2} + r^2 d\Omega^2 \right], \quad d\Omega^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2.\tag{2}$$

However, they only considered the flat case, $\kappa = 0$, but Sean Carroll claims that this is a Killing tensor without assuming flatness (see section 8.5, page 344, of his textbook, or chapter 8, page 228, in his [lecure notes](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/)). I have tried for a while now to verify this claim, but I have not managed to do so and would therefore appreciate your help.

### Partial results

By using $\nabla_\sigma g_{\mu\nu} = 0$, $\nabla_\sigma a^2 = \partial_\sigma a^2 = \delta_\sigma^0 2 a \dot a$, and the definition of $U^\mu$, I have found that

$$\nabla_\sigma K_{\mu\nu} = (g_{\mu\nu} + \delta_\mu^0 \delta_\nu^0)\delta_\sigma^0 2 a \dot a,\tag{3}$$

where $\dot a \equiv \partial_0 a$. This is diagonal in $\mu$ and $\nu$, and zero for $\sigma \ne 0$. I tried to use this to show that $\nabla_{(\sigma} K_{\mu\nu)} = 0$, but to no avail. Of course, I might have made a computation error somewhere along the way.

Comment: I'll point out that your condition can't even be true for the flat case, because $\kappa$ is not the reason that the permutations don't cancel.  I'd try a more general form for your $K$ tensor, like $K = \alpha g_{ab} + \beta u_{a}u_{b}$, and see if you can find a functional form for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that make your condition work out.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer From my own calculations, yes, I would agree that setting $\kappa = 0$ does not seem to fix the problem. However, in the linked question they do show it for the flat case (albeit with a different parametrization), and I cannot spot any obvious errors in their computations. Are you saying they are wrong?

Comment: I'm saying that it's easy to make little mistakes in copying over the ansatz, even with simple things like missing that the author is using the (+, -, -, -) signature or something

Comment: (and that the way to catch something like that is to add a little wiggle room in your expressions, and see if you can get a cancellation)  I think there's a 90% chance you're missing a sign or have a parenthesis in the wrong place.  Another thought is maybe the time coordinate is not the comiving one, but one that has a $r$ term that is proportional to $k$ or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this problem in detail, starting with the ansatz:

$u_{a} = (A, 0, 0, 0)$

$K_{ab} = \alpha g_{ab} + \beta u_{a}u_{b}$

With some laborious algebra, you find that the $ttt$ component of $\nabla_{c}K_{ab}$ vanishes if $\alpha = A^{2}\beta$, and for simplicity, assuming that there is not $r$ dependence in any of our unsolved functions.  Then, letting $q_{ab} = {\rm diag}(0, 0, 1, \sin^{2}\theta)$

$$\nabla_{c}K_{ab} = \delta_{a}^{r}\delta_{b}^{r}\delta_{c}^{t}\frac{a^{2}{\dot \alpha}}{1-kr^{2}} + a^{2}r^{2}{\dot \alpha}\delta_{c}^{t}q_{ab} - 2\frac{a{\dot a}\alpha}{1-kr^{2}}\delta_{(a}^{t}\delta_{b)}^{r}\delta_{c}^{r} - 2a {\dot a}r^{2}\alpha\delta_{(a}^{t}q_{b)c}$$

The RHS is manifestly symmetric in a and b, so, if permuting a and c is antisymmetric, then symmetrizing over abc will give zero.  Solving for this, you get the condition $2\frac{\dot a}{a} = \frac{\dot \alpha}{\alpha}$, which, choosing $A = -1$ (future-pointing lowered index), and $\alpha = a^{2}$ we get:

$u_{a} = (-1, 0, 0, 0)$

$K_{ab} = a^{2}(g_{ab} + u_{a}u_{b})$

Comment: Looking at your partial results section above, I suspect that you are missing some Christoffel symbols in your expression for $\nabla_{a}u_{b}$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through these laborious computations. Is it a typo when you write $u_a=(-1,0,0,0)$, because just above it you wrote $A=1$? Also, the sign of $A$ should not really matter should it?

Comment: I did not use any Christoffel symbols to get my partial result above. Instead I used something like $U_\mu U_\nu = (-\delta_\mu^0) (-\delta_\nu^0) = \delta_\mu^0 \delta_\nu^0$, and hence $\nabla_\sigma (U_\mu U_\nu) = 0$, say, by metric compatibility. Is this not correct?

Comment: @ummg: that is not correct.  $\nabla_{a}u_{b} = \partial_{a}u_{b} - \Gamma_{ab}{}^{c}u_{c} = \Gamma_{ab}{}^{t} =a {\dot a}h_{ab}$, where $h_{ab}$ is the 3-metric of the relevant slice

Comment: metric compatibility only gets you $\nabla_{a}g_{bc} = 0$, it gets you nothing for the derivatives of $u_{a}$

Comment: and yes, that sign is a typo.

Comment: Okay, I think I may see what the issue is. My thought was that, for $U^\mu=(1,0,0,0)^\mu=\delta^\mu_0$, we have $U_\mu U_\nu = g_{\mu\alpha} U^\alpha g_{\nu\beta} U^\beta = g_{\mu\alpha} \delta^\alpha_0 g_{\nu\beta} \delta^\beta_0 = g_{\mu 0} g_{\nu 0}$, and hence $\nabla_\sigma(U_\mu U_\nu) = \nabla_\sigma(g_{\mu 0} g_{\nu 0}) = 0$ by the chain rule and metric compatibility. But I'm thinking now that because $U^\mu=(1,0,0,0)^\mu$ is a coordinate dependent (non-tensorial) relation, this does not work. Is that correct, would you say?

Comment: @ummg : Once you've written down something like $g_{\mu 0}$, it's no longer the metric tensor, it's a set of components of the metric tensor.  Namely, it's still the one-form $u_{\mu}$, and that will transform like a one-form

Comment: irrespectively, explicit computation shows that its covariant derivative is nonzero.

Comment: Well, if it is true that $\nabla_{\sigma} g_{\mu\nu} = 0$, then certainly the special case $\nabla_{\sigma} g_{\mu 0} = 0$ is true as well. But other than that I agree with you, and I thank you for your help!

Comment: @ummg the order in which you set the index to zero is important.

if you think of $\nabla_{a}g_{b0}$ treating that 0 as a tensor index, then the expression is:  $\partial_{a}g_{b0} - \Gamma_{ab}{}^{c}g_{c0} - \Gamma_{a0}{}^{c}g_{bc}$, but if you interpret $g_{b0}$ as simply a vector (which is what you do when writing $u_{b}$ down), then you do not have that second Christoffel symbol, and the "metric compatibility" argument no longer works.